# Running java code on VMWare with references to external jar files

Tags: java, jar, classpath, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am trying to run simple java code on VMWare Workstation. I have the following simple test Main file:

```
import cern.jet.random.engine.RandomSeedGenerator;;

public class TestDataService {

    //private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestDataService.class);
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Hello World DAI!");

        // Input some data.
        RandomSeedGenerator re = new RandomSeedGenerator();
        return;
}
}
```

RandomSeedGenerator is a class in colt.jar library, and I have the jar file under my lib folder.

I am building the project with ant, and I have the following manifest file where I set the classpath:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: edu.umass.TestDataService
Name: edu/umass/TestDataService/Version.class
Class-Path: lib/colt.jar
```

When I run the code from the VMWare shell which runs Red Hat Linux, I get this Exception:

```
[root@localhost] java -jar app.jar

Hello World DAI!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cern/jet/random/engine/RandomSeedGenerator
at edu.umass.TestDataService.main (Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.long.ClassNotFoundException: cern.jet.random.engine.RandomSeedGenerator
```

Just as a final note, everything seems to work fine on windows with eclipse, but nothing seems to work on the virtual machine. Any ideas?

Comment: What if you try java -classpath .:lib/colt.jar -jar app.jar ?

Comment: No, it does not work--just tried again. When I was searching on the internet, it said if you run a jar file, you should specify the classpath in the manifest file and it ignores the environmental variable $CLASSPATH and also the -classpath specified explicitly in the command line--though I do not know how reliable this information.

Comment: I thought the classpath entry in the manifest only added in jars that were packaged INSIDE the jar file you are trying to run. If the jat is external, I think you have to leave the entry out of the manifest file and add it as a -classpath argument

Comment: Interesting! I actually just tried setting the classpath explicitly as you suggested, after removing the Classpath from the Manifest file. Not working! Thank you very much for the idea though!

Comment: What does jar -tvf lib/colt.Jar give you? Can you see the missing class in there?

Comment: jar tvf lib/colt.jar | grep RandomSeedG
  1140 Thu Sep 09 20:36:24 EDT 2004 cern/jet/random/engine/RandomSeedGenerator.class
kant:guarddog_umass hoktay$

Comment: Yes, I do see the missing class in the jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the jar files required by your application on the VMs?

Did you configured CLASS_PATH correctly?

Comment: Yes, all the files are in the filesystem of VMs. I tried different variations to configure the CLASSPATH. 1) Using Manifest file as described above 2)By setting an environmental variable in my .bashrc file 3)By explicitly specifying it on the command line as follows java -classpath lib/colt.jar -jar app.jar None of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is an issue with the jvm or the vm.  The problem is going to be in how you run the class. Specifically how your setting the classpath. Try this:

Navigate to where you've placed colt.jar. Get the present working directory by typing in pwd. Use this to construct the run command using the absolute path to colt.jar.

So eventually you should be running (from the directory containing your jar) something like this:

```
java -cp /the/full/path/to/lib/colt.jar -jar app.jar
```

Once you've got that work you can then try and figure out what the correct relative path is.  and then you'll be able to do

```
java -cp a/relativel/path/to/lib/colt.jar -jar app.jar
```

Comment: I tried the full path as well. It does not seem to work with the full path to the jar files. The same error!

Comment: @Huseyin Oktay. Okay let's rule out something simple. Unzip the colt.jar and see if cern/jet/random/engine.RandomSeedGenerator is in there.

Comment: jar tvf lib/colt.jar | grep RandomSeedG
  1140 Thu Sep 09 20:36:24 EDT 2004 cern/jet/random/engine/RandomSeedGenerator.class
Yes, the class is in the jar file.

Comment: @Husseyin Oktay. Well try moving the colt.jar to the same directory as app.jar and see if it works (remember to modify the classpath.) I'm sure you're getting something fundamental wrong with the classpath.